# Union tables into 1 with a flag indicating the respective table entries

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables.

1.home_shop

```
+---+------------+
|id | product    |   
+---+------------+
| 1 | soap       | 
| 2 | cake       | 
| 3 | biscuit    | 
+---+------------+
```

2.office_shop

```
+---+------------+
|id | product    |   
+---+------------+
| 1 | key        | 
| 2 | lock       | 
| 3 | pen        | 
+---+------------+
```

what i want is union this two tables into  a new table "complete_shop"  with a flag indicating "home" and "office"
for example:

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|id | product    |    flag     |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 | soap       | home        |
| 1 | key        | office      |
| 2 | cake       | home        |
| 2 | lock       | office      |
| 3 | biscuit    | home        |
| 3 | pen        | office      |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

how do i do this  union in mysql    please help me. i am a beginner

Comment: Why you have 2 different shops if you could store all in one shop with a outsourced flag. So you would have `shop(id, product, flag)` and `shop_type(id, name)` or for really good normalization you could do `shop(id, product, shop_type)`, `shop_type(id, name)` and `product(id, name)`

Comment: "for really good normalization" - what does that mean? They are already full normalized.

Answer (score 4):

Do a `UNION` query and introduce the `flag` column using the appropriate values.

```
SELECT id, product, 'home' AS flag
FROM home_shop
UNION ALL
SELECT id, product, 'office' AS flag
FROM office_shop
ORDER BY id, flag
```

Note that you don't need to use a subquery to order here, you can just specify the columns you want to use.